# UserJoined event handler not being called?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am building a bot with the Discord.net API.  One of the bot's functions is to welcome a new user.  This is done via an event handler hooked into the UserJoined event.

```
public class Program
{
    private DiscordSocketClient client;

    public async Task MainAsync()
    {
        client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig
        {
            LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug
        });

        client.UserJoined += Client_AnnounceJoinUser;

    }

    public async Task Client_AnnounceJoinUser(SocketGuildUser guildUser)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"[{DateTime.Now} at AnnounceJoinUser] a new user has joined!");
        var guild = client.GetGuild(//Guild Id);
        var channel = client.GetChannel(//Channel Id) as SocketTextChannel; 
        var rookieRole = guild.GetRole(//Role Id);

        await guildUser.AddRoleAsync(rookieRole);
        await channel.SendMessageAsync($"Hello {guildUser.Mention}, and welcome to {channel.Guild.Name}!/n/n{GetMessage(0)}");
    }
```

When a user is added to the guild, I receive logging from the gateway acknowledging.

> [12/8/2018 10:01:30 PM at Gateway] Received Dispatch (GUILD_MEMBER_ADD)

However, the client.UserJoined line to call the event handler is never run.  I've attempted placing a breakpoint here, but the breakpoint is never triggered.  I am speculating that the issue may lie in a failure to specify the guild to observe the UserJoined event in, but I am unsure how to proceed.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: wouldn't you need to pass something to the `Client_AnnounceJoinUser` function?

Comment: the code as posted would not compile due to lack of return from `public async Task MainAsync()`.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  This wasn't clear from the initial code I posted (oops), but my calling line for the event was at the bottom of my MainAsync task.  By moving the calling line for this (and other) event(s) above my lines for logging the bot in, the line runs and the event handler is successfully called.  My full MainAsync is below:

```
public async Task MainAsync()
    {
        client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig
        {
            LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug
        });

        Commands = new CommandService(new CommandServiceConfig
        {
            CaseSensitiveCommands = false,
            DefaultRunMode = RunMode.Async,
            LogLevel = LogSeverity.Debug
        });

        client.MessageReceived += Client_MessageReceived;
        await Commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

        client.Ready += Client_Ready;
        client.Log += Client_Log;
        client.UserJoined += Client_AnnounceJoinUser;
        client.GuildMemberUpdated += Client_AnnounceUpgradeUser;

        string token;
        FileStream stream = new FileStream($"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/data/token.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader readToken = new StreamReader(stream);
        token = readToken.ReadToEnd();

        await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, token);

        await client.StartAsync();

        await Task.Delay(-1);
    }
```